# Объясните постановку первых двух запятых в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

А вверху, без конца и без перерыва, тянул лесной шум, точно смутные вздохи старого бора.

Answer (score 1):

*А вверху, **без конца и без перерыва**, тянул лесной шум, точно смутные вздохи старого бора.*

Обстоятельственный оборот обособляется **со значением добавочного сообщения (дополнительного пояснения),  ставятся две запятые.**

1) Если поставить одну запятую, то между обстоятельствами  ***вверху*** и ***без конца и перерыва*** будут однородные отношения, а это не так. Обстоятельства разные, отвечают на вопросы (где ? как?).

2) **Если не ставить запятые вообще**, то отношения между обстоятельствами будут обозначены как **неоднородные** (и это действительное так), но понять смысл такого предложения сложно (к примеру, неясно будет, что связывает союз И). Да и для  чтения этот вариант неудобен ввиду распространенности обстоятельств.

**Сравнить:** *А вверху **непрерывно** тянул лесной шум, точно смутные вздохи старого бора.* Здесь обособление не требуется (обстоятельства нераспространенные, союза И нет).

**Другой пример:** *Летом в комнатах и на балконе очень жарко.* Здесь грамматическая структура та же самая, но обстоятельства явно неоднородные (места и времени) и нераспространенные. Соответственно, обособление тоже не требуется.

3) Поэтому методом исключения получаем, что вариант с обособлением для данного предложения  **наиболее приемлем.** Этот выбор определяется структурой предложения  и семантикой обстоятельств.